# Java OpenCV FileStorage and Mat.push_back

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement [this](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Cpp/blob/master/GenData.cpp) project, namely GenData.cpp, (written in C++) in Java for KNN classifier. 
I've reached these lines of code and stuck:

```
matClassificationInts.push_back(intChar);
cv::FileStorage fsClassifications("classifications.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fsClassifications << "classifications" << matClassificationInts;
fsClassifications.release();
```

In c++ we can pass integer to push_back(), but in Java I'm getting error: "int cannot be converted to Mat".
So, the first question is: how can I pass int to someMat.push_back()?
And the second one: how could I implement FileStorage in Java or write Mat to *.xml format (and read Mat from *.xml)?

so far, my code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import org.opencv.core.Core;
    import static org.opencv.core.CvType.CV_32FC1;
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    import org.opencv.core.MatOfInt4;
    import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
    import org.opencv.core.Rect;
    import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
    import org.opencv.core.Size;
    import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
    import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
    import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C;
    import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE;
    import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL;
    import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV;

    public class genData {

    private static final int 
            MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 100,
            RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20,
            RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); 

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;

        Mat imgTrainingNumbers;
        Mat imgGrayscale = new Mat();
        Mat imgBlurred = new Mat();
        Mat imgThresh = new Mat();
        Mat imgThreshCopy = new Mat();

        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> ptContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        MatOfInt4 v4iHierarchy;
        Mat matClassificationInts = new Mat();
        Mat matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats = new Mat();

        int[] intValidChars = { '0', '1', '2',
        'A', 'B', 'C'}; //Here I did not make List<Integer>, because I can't pass char to Integer.
        Arrays.sort(intValidChars); //for binary search

        imgTrainingNumbers = Imgcodecs.imread("test.png"); //here Text on white paper.

        if (imgTrainingNumbers.empty()) {
            System.out.println("err");
            return;
        }

        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgTrainingNumbers, imgGrayscale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, imgBlurred, new Size(5, 5), 0);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred, imgThresh, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2);

        /*
        //imshow class implementation (found via google, works properly, but this block is commented for now)
        Imshow im = new Imshow("imgThresh");
        im.showImage(imgThresh);
        imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.clone();
        */

        Imgproc.findContours(imgThreshCopy, ptContours, new Mat(), RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


        for (int i = 0; i < ptContours.size(); i++) {
            if (Imgproc.contourArea(ptContours.get(i)) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA) {
                Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(ptContours.get(i));
                Imgproc.rectangle(imgTrainingNumbers, boundingRect.tl(), boundingRect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
                Mat matROI = imgThresh.submat(boundingRect.y, boundingRect.y + boundingRect.height, boundingRect.x, boundingRect.x + boundingRect.width);
                Mat matROIResized = new Mat();
                Imgproc.resize(matROI, matROIResized, new Size(RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT));
                /*
                im.showImage(matROI);
                im.showImage(matROIResized);
                im.showImage(imgTrainingNumbers);
                */
                String input = keyboard.nextLine();
                int intChar = (int)input.charAt(0);
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(intValidChars, intChar) >=0) {
                    /*
                    matClassificationInts.push_back(intChar);
                    //Here I'm getting an error.
                    */
                    Mat matImageFloat = new Mat();
                    matROIResized.convertTo(matImageFloat, CV_32FC1);
                    Mat matImageFlattenedFloat = matImageFloat.reshape(1, 1);
                    matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.push_back(matImageFlattenedFloat);
                }
            }
        }
       //Here should go FileStorage stuff.
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance. 
P.S. Using OpenCV_310 + Java (not JavaCV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've made solution by myself. **Pretty dirty**, I guess, but it is what it is. If you know how to make good improvements to my code, I'll glad to read your comments. 
1) My first question was about putting an int into Mat (for making *.xml in further). I avoided that approach, and decided to put int (actually Integer) into List.

```
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 String input = keyboard.nextLine();
 int intChar = (int)input.charAt(0);
 List<Integer> matClassificationInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 if (Arrays.binarySearch(intValidChars, intChar) >=0) {
    matClassificationInts.add(new Integer(intChar));
    ......
 }
 String dataImages = "";
 for (Integer i : matClassificationInts) {
     dataImages += i + " ";
 }
```

And I could make String (like "49 48" chars <-> "1 0" ints, for example) for saving it in *.xml (see next paragraph). 
2) Second question was about extraction data from Mat and storing it in *.xml. Well, via C++ I can make it by FileStorage:

```
cv::FileStorage fsClassifications("classifications.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fsClassifications << "classifications" << matClassificationInts;
fsClassifications.release();
```

But Java OpenCV has no such feature, so I loop through 2d-array (Mat.rows() and Mat.cols()) and exctract needed data via get() method (Mat.get(row, col) - gives array of double, length of array = 1):

```
String dataClassifications = "";
for (int i = 0; i < matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.rows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.cols(); j++) {
        double[] temp = matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.get(i, j);
        dataClassifications += temp[0] + " ";
    }
    dataClassifications += "\n";
}
```

Now, about saving data to *.xml: 
I just used *javafx.xml* and *org.wc3.dom* libs. 
Made two functions for returing DOM-nodes:

```
private static Node getMatXML(Document doc, String option_id, String type_id, String rows, String cols, String dt, String data) {
    Element elem = doc.createElement(option_id);
    elem.setAttribute("type_id", type_id);
    elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc,"rows", rows));
    elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc, "cols", cols));
    elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc, "dt", dt));
    elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc, "data", data));
    return elem;
}

private static Node getMatXMLElement(Document doc, String name, String value) {
    Element node = doc.createElement(name);
    node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
    return node;
}
```

And used these functions for creating *.xml:
Classifications.xml:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory_images = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder icBuilder_images;
    try {
        icBuilder_images = icFactory_images.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = icBuilder_images.newDocument();
        Element mainRootElement = doc.createElement("opencv_storage");
        doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);
        mainRootElement.appendChild(getMatXML(doc, "classifications", "opencv-matrix", rowsImages, colsImages, "i", dataImages));
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        String filename = "classifications.xml";
        File file = new File(filename);
        StreamResult console = new StreamResult(file); //(System.out)
        transformer.transform(source, console);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Images.xml:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory_classifications = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder icBuilder_classifications;
    try {
        icBuilder_classifications = icFactory_classifications.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = icBuilder_classifications.newDocument();
        Element mainRootElement = doc.createElement("opencv_storage");
        doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);
        mainRootElement.appendChild(getMatXML(doc, "images", "opencv-matrix", rowsClassifications, colsClassifications, "f", dataClassifications));
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        String filename = "images.xml";
        File file = new File(filename);
        StreamResult console = new StreamResult(file); //(System.out)
        transformer.transform(source, console);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, for example, generated classifications file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<opencv_storage>
<classifications type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>2</rows>
<cols>1</cols>
<dt>i</dt>
<data>49 48 </data>
</classifications>
</opencv_storage>
```

I did test for this pic:
[image: 01]
 via GenData.cpp (see link in question - 1st line) and my Java code (full code see below). Both programs gave me the same result: 
***For Java OpenCV Imshow implementation you can take a look [this link](https://github.com/master-atul/ImShow-Java-OpenCV) (not mine).***

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import static org.opencv.core.CvType.CV_32FC1;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfInt4;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C;
import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE;
import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL;
import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV;

//XML - write.
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class genData {


    private static final int 
            MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 100,
            RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20,
            RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        Mat imgTrainingNumbers;
        Mat imgGrayscale = new Mat();
        Mat imgBlurred = new Mat();
        Mat imgThresh = new Mat();
        Mat imgThreshCopy = new Mat();

        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> ptContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        MatOfInt4 v4iHierarchy = new MatOfInt4();

        List<Integer> matClassificationInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Mat matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats = new Mat();

        int[] intValidChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'H',
        'K', 'M', 'O', 'P', 'T',
        'X', 'Y'};
        Arrays.sort(intValidChars);

        imgTrainingNumbers = Imgcodecs.imread("01.png");

        if (imgTrainingNumbers.empty()) {
            System.out.println("Error: file is not found");
            return;
        }

        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgTrainingNumbers, imgGrayscale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, imgBlurred, new Size(5, 5), 0);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred, imgThresh, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2);

        Imshow im = new Imshow("imgThresh");
        im.showImage(imgThresh);
        imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.clone();

        Imgproc.findContours(imgThreshCopy, ptContours, v4iHierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


        for (int i = 0; i < ptContours.size(); i++) {
            if (Imgproc.contourArea(ptContours.get(i)) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA) {
                Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(ptContours.get(i));
                Imgproc.rectangle(imgTrainingNumbers, boundingRect.tl(), boundingRect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
                Mat matROI = imgThresh.submat(boundingRect.y, boundingRect.y + boundingRect.height, boundingRect.x, boundingRect.x + boundingRect.width);
                Mat matROIResized = new Mat();
                Imgproc.resize(matROI, matROIResized, new Size(RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT));
                im.showImage(matROI);
                im.showImage(matROIResized);
                im.showImage(imgTrainingNumbers);
                String input = keyboard.nextLine();
                int intChar = (int)input.charAt(0);
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(intValidChars, intChar) >=0) {
                    matClassificationInts.add(new Integer(intChar));
                    Mat matImageFloat = new Mat();
                    matROIResized.convertTo(matImageFloat, CV_32FC1);
                    Mat matImageFlattenedFloat = matImageFloat.reshape(1, 1);
                    matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.push_back(matImageFlattenedFloat);
                }
            }
        }

        String dataImages = "";
        for (Integer i : matClassificationInts) {
            dataImages += i + " ";
        }

        String dataClassifications = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.rows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.cols(); j++) {
                double[] temp = matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.get(i, j);
                dataClassifications += temp[0] + " ";
            }
            dataClassifications += "\n";
        }

        String rowsImages = String.valueOf(matClassificationInts.size());
        String colsImages = "1";
        String rowsClassifications = String.valueOf(matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.rows());
        String colsClassifications = String.valueOf(matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.cols());

        DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory_images = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder icBuilder_images;
        try {
            icBuilder_images = icFactory_images.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = icBuilder_images.newDocument();
            Element mainRootElement = doc.createElement("opencv_storage");
            doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);
            mainRootElement.appendChild(getMatXML(doc, "classifications", "opencv-matrix", rowsImages, colsImages, "i", dataImages));
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            String filename = "classifications.xml";
            File file = new File(filename);
            StreamResult console = new StreamResult(file); //(System.out)
            transformer.transform(source, console);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory_classifications = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder icBuilder_classifications;
        try {
            icBuilder_classifications = icFactory_classifications.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = icBuilder_classifications.newDocument();
            Element mainRootElement = doc.createElement("opencv_storage");
            doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);
            mainRootElement.appendChild(getMatXML(doc, "images", "opencv-matrix", rowsClassifications, colsClassifications, "f", dataClassifications));
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            String filename = "images.xml";
            File file = new File(filename);
            StreamResult console = new StreamResult(file); //(System.out)
            transformer.transform(source, console);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished.");
        System.exit(0);
    }   

    private static Node getMatXML(Document doc, String option_id, String type_id, String rows, String cols, String dt, String data) {
        Element elem = doc.createElement(option_id);
        elem.setAttribute("type_id", type_id);
        elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc,"rows", rows));
        elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc, "cols", cols));
        elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc, "dt", dt));
        elem.appendChild(getMatXMLElement(doc, "data", data));
        return elem;
    }

    private static Node getMatXMLElement(Document doc, String name, String value) {
        Element node = doc.createElement(name);
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
        return node;
    }
}
```